# Drupal website node edit tabs not producing "normal" url's

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have inherited a Drupal website from a big name firm who did not provide documentation.
I have worked with drupal for almost four years and have never experienced anything like this.
All the node edit tabs on the site have weird urls. Lets say the "path" for a node is setup to be

content/node-title

the edit tab will have a url of

content/node-title/edit

instead of the usual url of

node/nid/edit

Does anybody know what might be causing this. I assume it is a module, but can not locate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My shot in the dark would be the "Sub-path URL Aliases" module working in conjunction with Pathauto and Global Redirect.

Pathauto defines the nice URL's (e.g. content/node-title), GR enforces them, and Sub-path URL Aliases ensures subpaths look pretty, too.

Check out:
http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias

If that isn't it, please let us know if you find the answer.